# VBA Loop Until ignoring second condition

Tags: excel, vba, loops, conditional-statements

My `RootCheck2` is designed to check if it is in fact a root or instead a vertical asymptote. It seems to be ignoring that second condition as the code is currently outputting both asymptotes and roots. The `Oldx` that the code outputs gives an `fOldx` greater than 5, leading me to believe that it's ignoring the second condition. Please let me know if I'm missing anything, thank you

```vb
Public Function SearchPsi(ByVal Variables As Range, ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Dim Oldx As Double
    Dim Checkx As Double
    Dim fx As Double
    Dim fOldx As Double
    Dim fCheckx As Double
    Dim RootCheck1 As Boolean
    Dim RootCheck2 As Boolean
    
    Do
        Oldx = x
        x = Oldx + 0.1
        Checkx = Oldx + 0.01
        fx = PSI(Variables, x)
        fOldx = PSI(Variables, Oldx)
        fCheckx = PSI(Variables, Checkx)
        
        If (fx * fOldx) < 0 Then
            RootCheck1 = True
        End If
        
        If Abs(fOldx) < 5 Then
            RootCheck2 = True
        End If
    Loop Until RootCheck1 = True And RootCheck2 = True
    
    SearchPsi = Oldx
End Function
```

Comment: Once `RootCheck1` or `RootCheck2` make it to `True`, they will never become `False`, because you never set them to `False` when your conditions do not hold.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do
    Oldx = x
    x = Oldx + 0.1
    Checkx = Oldx + 0.01
    fx = PSI(Variables, x)
    fOldx = PSI(Variables, Oldx)
    fCheckx = PSI(Variables, Checkx)

Loop Until (fx * fOldx) < 0 And Abs(fOldx) < 5
```